# Why does ERDAS not like my GDAL output?

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, erdas-imagine

I am creating a raster using GDAL and the IMAGINE file doesn't work in ERDAS because it doesn't recognize the projection.

Here is the code to generate a sample:

```
from osgeo import gdal

projectionWkt = """PROJCS["Albers Conical Equal Area",GEOGCS["NAD83",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9108"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],PROJECTION["Albers_Conic_Equal_Area"],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",29.5],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",45.5],PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",23],PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",-96],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["meters",1]]"""

outputRaster = gdal.GetDriverByName("HFA").Create("test.img",10,10,1,gdal.GDT_FLoat32)
outputRaster.setProjection(projectionWkt)
```

This file does work in ArcMap, but can't be used in ERDAS.

Am I doing something wrong with GDAL?

Comment: A guess: try changing the projection name to "Albers" from "Albers_Conic_Equal_Area". That's actually an alias supported by ArcGIS for...Oracle? EPSG? Can't remember off-hand.

Comment: @mkennedy nope :/ just tried it and ERDAS still can't use it.